# wget security.ubuntu.com not working on ubuntu

Tags: apt, security, wget

We are able to use wget for other URLs, such as google.com, but wget security.ubuntu.com not working and giving output:

```
Resolving security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.92.200, 91.189.92.201, 91.189.88.149, ...
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)|91.189.92.200|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
```

And apt-get also not working. The apt-get install php5-curl giving following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  checkbox gnome-dictionary gnome-search-tool libgdict-1.0-6 libgdict-common printer-driver-hpijs python3-checkbox
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-gd php5-mysql php5-readline
Suggested packages:
  php-pear php5-user-cache
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-curl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-gd php5-mysql php5-readline
6 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 283 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,864 kB of archives.
After this operation, 142 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  php5-readline php5-cli php5-mysql php5-gd libapache2-mod-php5 php5-common php5-curl
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
0% [Connecting to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13)]
```

But another server in the same VPC which is actually a copy of the AMI on Amazon is also working. The configuration is exactly the same on both servers (the one that works and the one that doesn’t).

The external IP Addresses of server that not works:

54.210.0.128
54.210.0.13

Thanks

Comment: Those IP addresses (54.210.0.13 & 54.210.0.13) don't ping back for me, maybe their server is down. 20 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 19002ms

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then please post any errors.

If there are no errors, use `sudo apt-get install` followed by the package name again.

If you want to download something from the Ubuntu archives use `apt-get download` without sudo and followed by the package name to download whatever package you need to your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Putting in security.ubuntu.com in my webbrowser redirects it to www.ubuntu.com/usn that might be why you can't download the site. "wget" is used to download the target address.

For your apt-get problem, try changing the ubuntu server for updates. That usually works.

Comment: The index page redirects to USN, but http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu, the URL used by apt, works fine.